# Having issues Flushing Parse Facebook login cache

Tags: javascript, facebook, caching, parse-platform

I am creating a javascript web application and am wanting to make it so that the username is cleared each time the page is called. I google searched my problem and was informed that I would have use the Facebook sdk in order to delete the cache. I can't seem to figure out what I have to call to get rid of the cache.

Here is a link to the Javascript Facebook sdk: [Facebook SDK for Javascript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/v2.5)